# Ubuntu 1 TB hard disk format

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, format

I have external hard drive which is 1TB.

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and it was working fine
then i have replace with internal hard disk to solid state drive[SSD]  and that also working fine.

but now i want to use my laptop internal hard disk which 1T as external hard drive and i am unable to do that.

#### i have tried to format 12 to 13th times but i am unable to do that.

[image: Error message]
Please help me out.

Comment: What error messages do you get when you create a partition on */dev/sdb* ?

Comment: there is no such option available to create a partition for /dev/sdb.

Comment: i have tried this command sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb but not getting any output.

Comment: Your not going to be able to add a partition while `dd` is running.

Comment: Are you trying to format the drive like sdb, not a partition like sdb1?

Answer (score 0):

Many times, when moving a hard disk from internal, to an external hard disk enclosure (or the other way), requires that the hard disk be reinitialized. Any existing data or partition structure will be reset. This has to do with the hardware used on the expansion enclosure's **USB to SATA bridge card**.

Assuming that you have no hardware issue, just start `gparted`, create a new MBR or GPT partition table, create a new ext4 or NTFS partition(s), and you're good to go. GPT is the preferred partition table type, and NTFS is the preferred partition type if you're planning on sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: gparted also throwing input/output error.

Comment: @vinaykumar Does the external enclosure have its own power supply, or does it only get power from the USB port? It may not have enough power for the 1TB hard drive. Or you may have a hardware problem with the external enclosure's **USB to SATA bridge**, or with the hard disk itself. Remove the hard disk from the enclosure, connect its SATA interface directly to the computer, and retry to format it. If that works, then your external enclosure is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it is getting power supply from USB port.

Comment: @vinaykumar Either add an external power supply to the external enclosure, if that's an option, or try a powered USB hub, or remove the drive from the enclosure as I mentioned earlier.